# Error: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

My code is like this. Whenever i call this function --

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

function userID($username){
    mysql_connect($localhost, $user, $password);
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
    $q = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE Username='$username'";
    $query = mysql_query($q);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $return_value = $row['ID'];
    }
    return $return_value;
}
```

-- I get this error --

```
Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

what is wrong? Please tell me?

Comment: The db connection needs a password.

Comment: everything is default and when i run this its work fine mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")

Answer (score 0):

Either your username, password, or both are wrong.